# Por qué 'data.Search' es 'undefined' en este código de React?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, undefined

Bueno, para practicar ReactJS estoy intentando hacer mi propia Pokedex. Veo que hay muchos ejemplos en internet, pero con la intención de retarme a mi mismo he decidido intentar hacerla mayormente por mi cuenta. La cosa es que veo que es muy difícil a mi nivel y lo más seguro es que tenga que usar una guía.

Por ejemplo, aquí me atasco y no se qué ocurre:

```
const search = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      axios.get(API_URL + state.handle).then(({ data }) => {
        let results = data.Search;

        setState((prevState) => {
          return { ...prevState, results: results };
        });
      });
    }
  };
```

He revisado mi código y todo parece funcionar perfecto, pero este punto me falla. Si hago `console.log` en el `API_URL + state.handle`, veo que la búsqueda es correcta, pues me sale el **enlace correcto de la API de Pokemon**. Sin embargo, en el siguiente punto, a la hora de pasar el `data.Search` a una variable falla, porque me da `undefined`.

Entiendo que es algo complejo y que hace falta mucho más código para entenderlo, pero, ¿podríais a primera vista deducir qué puede estar pasando? ¿Por qué es `undefined`? Hay que añadir que este mismo código lo uso en otro proyecto, con una **API de películas** en ese caso, para hacer un buscador de películas, y funciona corréctamente. Deduzco pues que el problema reside en la forma de invocar, llamar o utilizar la **API**, ¿no?

Alguna ayuda? Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Todo se ve bien, lo mas probable es que la API de pokemón te regrese los datos con una estructura diferente a tu proyecto de películas, por que no imprimes exactamente lo que recibes en `data`, si es así lo único que habría que hacer es re configurar como obtienes los datos *e.g.* Quiza los datos están en data.searchResult.content.

Comment: Gracias por tu interés amigo. La cosa es que he probado a cambiar el destructuring y ya me ha funcionado. Luego el `let` lo hice `const` y algunos cambios más. Te agradezco tu consejo!